# Strange center of mass equation in AP Physics C

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames

My post is an elaboration of those [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/371444/curiosity-over-center-of-mass-equation) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/624015/trouble-understanding-the-center-of-mass-equation).

In my AP Physics C class, I was introduced to the following equation for center of mass (CM):
$$x_\text{cm} = \frac 1M \int x\, dm.$$
Above, $dm$ represents a "slice" of the given object.

Problems would then be solved using the below format:

> **Prompt**: "Find the CM of a metal rod with
> constant density, mass $M$, and length $L$."
>
> Observe that $M/L = dm/dx$ so $dm = \frac{M}{L}\, dx$. Then:
> $$\begin{align*}x_\text{cm} &= \frac 1M \int x \, dm \\ 
> &= \frac 1M \int \frac ML x\, dx \\
> &= \int^L_0 \frac{x}{L} \tag 1 \\
> &= \frac{L}{2}\end{align*}$$
> The boundaries of integrations at (1) appear since the object ranges from $x = 0$ and $x = L$. They are not specified in the formula though because we don't necessarily integrate over $x$. For more examples of this form of problem-solving, see [Dan Fullterton's video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RbAe_xPZL4Y)

I am confused by the statement:

> "Observe that $M/L = dm/dx$ so $dm = \frac{M}{L}\, dx$."

Manipulation of $dx$ and $dm$ is mathematically undefined since infinitesimals aren't variables.

Since I couldn't understand the class-provided technique, I ended up employing the equation below for an object spanning $x = a$ to $x = b$:
$$x_\text{cm} = \frac 1M \int^a_b \lambda(x) x\, dx.$$
Above, $\lambda(x) = \rho (x) \cdot A(x)$ where $\rho(x)$ provides the average density at the object's intersection with the plane at $x$, and $A(x)$ is the area of that intersection.

Is this a valid alternative equation? Also, how does the earlier technique work in a technical sense?

Comment: *Manipulation of  and   is mathematically undefined since infinitesimals aren't variables* The fun thing about physics is that you can do so and it does work.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92925/25301 and some of the linked posts on the side

Comment: You do not have to use "undefined infinitesimals." The symbol "$\frac{dm}{dx}$" can be taken to mean the derivative of $m(x)$ with respect to $x$. If you would prefer, go ahead and write it like $m'(x)=\frac{M}{L}$. You still need to change variables in your integral. A la: $\int dm f(m) = \int dx m'(x) f(m(x))$, no "undefined infinitesimals" needed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Observe that $M/L=\mathrm{d}m/\mathrm{d}x$ so $\mathrm{d}m=\frac{M}{L}\mathrm{d}x$

This really isn't the best way to state this. A more clear way is that for a uniformly dense rod, the [*linear (mass) density*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_density) is $\lambda=M/L$. But since the mass density is constant, we can also say that for an infinitesimal slice of the rod, the mass of the slice is $\mathrm{d}m$ and must be equal to the product of the density and the (infinitesimal) length, $\mathrm{d}x$:<sup>1</sup>
$$\mathrm{d}m=\lambda\,\mathrm{d}x$$

You can then [substitute this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) into your COM equation,
$$\frac{1}{M}\int_{0}^{M} x\,\mathrm{d}m=\frac{1}{M}\int_{0}^{L} x\lambda\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{M}\int_{0}^{L} x\frac{M}{L}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^{L} x\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{L}{2}$$
Note that in the first equality, when we made the change of variables, we had to change the limits of the integrals--it was easy in this case, but in some other changes of variables yield more difficult limit changes.

This method is essentially equivalent to the alternative method you've discovered yourself.

<sup>1. Note this would also be equivalent to saying that the mass density is the derivative of the mass with respect to the position: $\lambda=\mathrm{d}m/\mathrm{d}x$.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Your alternative equation is valid.

A more technical way of understanding the mathematically undefined equation is by multiplying both sides by $x$ and then integrating both sides with respect to $dx$:

$$\frac{M}{L} = \frac{dm}{dx},$$

$$\int{x\frac{M}{L}} dx = \int{x\frac{dm}{dx}} dx.$$

Now, we can substitute $dx = \frac{dx}{dm} dm$ on the right side:

$$\int{x\frac{M}{L}} dx = \int{x \frac{dm}{dx} \frac{dx}{dm} dm}.$$

And then we simplify $\frac{dm}{dx} \frac{dx}{dm} = 1$, and we're left with the desired expression:

$$\int{x\frac{M}{L}} dx = \int{x dm}.$$

Comment: OP has expressed concerns with multiplying/dividing infinitesimals, which your answer uses repeatedly.

Comment: Nope, this answer never multiplies or divides any infinitesimals.

Comment: Then how does $(dm/dx)(dx/dm)=1$?

Comment: See here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292590/is-frac-mathrmdx-mathrmdy-frac1-left-frac-mathrmdy

Comment: Okay, so you're multiplying. Got it, glad we cleared that up.

Comment: I'm not multiplying infinitesimals though, I'm multiplying total derivatives.

Comment: This answer is correct and appears to address OP's concerns, its just that Travis is writing $\frac{dm}{dx}$, which is abhorrent to OP. But Travis is taking the entire symbol "$\frac{dm}{dx}$" not as a "fraction" but as a derivative. It might be less abhorrent to OP if "$\frac{dm}{dx}$" was written as "$m'(x)$."

Answer (score 1):

the mass is equal to the density time volume

$$M=\rho\,V$$
thus if the density $~\rho~$ is constant then
$$dM=\rho\,dV=\rho\,A\,dx$$

where the area $~A~$ is constant

$\Rightarrow$

$$\frac{dM}{M}=\frac{\rho\,A\,dx}{\rho\,V}=\frac{\rho\,A\,dx}{\rho\,A\,L}=
\frac{dx}{L}$$

Answer (score -1):

For your uniform density rod of constant cross-section,

[image]

and the relationship follows.

If you do not like the way that $dm/dx$ was used as a fraction then go back one step and use the fraction $\delta m/\delta x$, do the algebra, and then take a limit $\delta x\to 0$ for the summation which is where the integral comes from.

Your use of $\lambda(x) = \rho (x) \cdot A(x)$ is fine and note that $\lambda(x) \cdot dx= \underbrace{\rho (x)\,A(x)\,dx}_{dm}$.